# iOS - This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (corrupt file).

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using CoreData in my iOS app to allow the user to save some data to his phone, and whenever I make an update, I am getting only one or two users that have the following crash message:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
```

This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (corrupt file). It cannot perform a save operation.

Multiple times though, which indicates that they simply can't open the app anymore, it crashes on every relaunch. This only happens to 1, maximum 2 users out of a couple of thousand, and it's impossible for me to replicate this.

```
    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"modelName" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"app name.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                              NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption : @YES
                              };
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

This is the CoreData stack in my AppDelegate.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you update the model at some point and then tried to save?

Comment: I did update the model at some point, though weirdly this issue already existed beforehand. I only did a lightweight migration though and followed tutorials online -- and it worked for 99.9% of my users, which is really weird.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem

Comment: Sadly I never did. Ended up completely redoing my models.